# How to return zero in a calculated field

Tags: ms-access

I have 4 tables for 4 departments. The tables all have same fields (test, amount, discount, amount paid, payment date). A user can only see form that add data to each table based on their department.

I have a datasheet form of which I have added unbounded textboxes on the form footer that return sums of the fields: amount, discount, and amount paid. I use the datasheet form as a subform on a main form. On the main form I have unbound textboxes that return values from the form footer of the subforms. I also have unbound textbox that sum up the values as totals from the unbound textboxes that return values from the subforms. Everything worked perfectly until I deleted all the values from one of the department tables. Now the unbound textbox returns values from the empty table returns "error" and the textbox that sums up all values returns "type!".

I have tried changing the calculated textbox control source on the subform to
`=sum(iif(isnull([amount]), "0", [amount]))`
but it does not work.

I have used this for all the unbound textboxes on subform footer changing their field name respectively.

Because one of the tables contains no data it returns error on the main form. How do I solve this problem so that if one of the tables have no data the form can still do the calculations. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of 4 tables should be 1 table with a field for department and apply filter criteria. You deleted all records from table or just data in a field?

Comment: The departments receives different information even though they have same fields. I deleted records in just one table

Comment: Nz is not working

Comment: I just did a test where subform has no records. The main form calc does not error, the textbox is blank (null). Then used Nz() and calc shows value. No error messages at all. **Don't use quote marks around 0.** That would cause Type! error. Again, if tables have same fields, should be 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Nz*:

```
=Sum(Nz([amount], 0))
```